# Vue.js Property or method "columns" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

Where am I making mistakes? I'm the beginner when it comes to Vue.js. Can somebody help me and explain? I'm trying to make the table filters.

namespace App\Http\Controllers\cofus\reports;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Client;

class ClientController extends Controller{

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:admin');    
}

public function allClients()
{
    $clients = Client::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);

    return view('cofus.reports.clients')->with('clients', $clients);
}

public function getData()
{
    $model = Client::searchPaginateAndOrder();
    $columns =Client::$columns;

    response()
        ->json([
            'model' => $model,
            'columns' => $columns
        ]);
}
```

}

web.php

Route::prefix('cofus')->group(function(){

```
Route::get('/reports/clients', 'cofus\reports\ClientController@allClients')->name('reports.clients');

Route::get('/api/clients', 'cofus\reports\ClientController@getData');
```

});

localhost:8088/cofus/cofus/reports/clients

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">

  <clients  source="/cofus/cofus/api/clients" title="Client Data"></clients> 

  <option v-for="column in columns" :value="column"></option>

</div>
```

```js
<script>
var clients = Vue.component('clients',{

  props: ['source', 'title'],
  data(){
    return {
      model: {},
      columns: {}
    }
  },
  
  render: function created(){
    this.fetchIndexData()
  },

  methods: {
     fetchIndexData(){
      var vm = this
      axios.get(this.source)
      .then(function(response) {
        Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
        Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)
      })
      .catch(function(response){
        console.log(response)
      })
    }
  }

});
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
})

</script>
```

Comment: Just as your error tells, there is no property / method defined with the name `columns`, what exactly does the `response` return here `Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)`, could you post the result of it into your question

Comment: You have `option` defined outside of `clients`. the `<option>` can't know about `:columns` because it's a `locally scoped variable` to the `clients component`.

Comment: When console.log(Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)) give me array of columns. Don't now how display that from axios to HTML.